# Why flutter always loading latest library

Tags: flutter

In my `pubspec.yaml` file, I have declared flutter toast version 5.0.3 but it always downloading the 5.0.5 why

[image]

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've used ^ arrow. Using the ^ will download latest version of the library. Remove the ^ to download the exact version.